# How to use templated links in Apache Superset

Tags: jinja2, apache-superset

In the time series table chart of Apache Superset, there is an option to create a "templated link" using the url field where it appears you can make the metric being displayed, for example, a link to another website or dashboard.

I have not found any documentation on how this is done and I am struggling to understand how this can be done. my ultimate goal is to allow a user to click on the metric of interest which will redirect to another pre-filtered dashboard.

[image: url parameter in the time series table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do what you want. Currently the URL field has access to the `metric` object of each row, which has the following attributes (this is an example for a simple `COUNT(*)` metric):

```js
{
  certification_details: null,​
  certified_by: null,
  d3format: null,
​  description: null,
​​  expression: "COUNT(*)",
  id: 24,
​  is_certified: false,
​​  metric_name: "count",
​​  verbose_name: "COUNT(*)",
​​  warning_text: null,
}
```

​
So if you set URL to `https://example.com/{{ metric.metric_name }}` the metric name in the table will be a link pointing to `https://example.com/count` in this example (see the link at the bottom left of the screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Hey Beto, thanks a lot! I actually did not know you could paste a URL prior to adding the {{metric}} parameter. If the metric used in the table is a factor such as a list of countries and customer clicks on that link, I should be able to pass the metric to the preselect filters of another dashboard therefore allowing me to get my "drill down" e.g. another dashboard filtered on a specific selection of the data.

Comment: for some reason {{ metric.metric_name }} doesnt produce anything in apache superset 0.38. Not sure this is going to work anymore

Comment: Can you try enabling the `ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING` feature flag in your config?